# Истребовать У или ОТ

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Истребовать у (от) работника заявление..."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне кажется, тут несколько разный смысл. Если требовать ОТ работника, определяющим тут является тот факт, что заявление предоставлено этим работником. А если У - это уже характеризует некое конктертное действие: подошли к работнику некие злые люди и потребовали заявление))